# How to change CollectionView cell width according to label text in swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, label, width

I need to change collectionview cell width according to its label text like this

[image]

for that i have given collectionview constraints

```
top, leading, trailing, = 10 height = 80
```

in cell i have placed label inside uiview, i have placed uiview because i need to give corner radious

and code

```
class SearchFilterVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


var textArray = ["hbdhwebhj", "behgwfhjewgbkfjbe", "hbhjs", "bdhsbfhegu", "gwdgyqwuguq"]


@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

           let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout        
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return textArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SearchFilterCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SearchFilterCollectionViewCell
       
    
    cell.textLabel.text = textArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
}
}
```

edit:

[image]

o/p

[image]

how to over come from this issue, please do help with code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All items in your collectionView are taking the exact same size because you have specified `layout.itemSize` for your collectionView's flow layout

remove `layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.size.width / 2, height: 80)`

**Other issues in code:**

1. `layout.invalidateLayout()` is unnecessary in `ViewDidLoad`
2. `if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {` to set `minimumInteritemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing` is unnecessary, in a statement just above it you have created `let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()` why dont you simply set `minimumInteritemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing` there itself? Why use additional `if let`?

Simply write

```
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

You need not specify item size, Collection view flow layout is set to be horizontal in nature, so by default each item will take the same height as the collection view height and if you have only one label inside the cell and if you have set autolayout constraint properly, label's intrinsic content size will ensure cell gets proper width

[image]

And forwhatever reason if you decide to wrap the label inside a `UIView` logic above holds good, as long as you set the label's autolayout constraint right, lablel's intrinsic content size will set the width of the containerView and which will in turn contribute to set the cell's width appropriately,

Here cell has background color of red, container view has orange and label has no background color, I have added leading and trailing spacing between cell and view as 10, and label and container view has leading and trailing space as 5

[image]

**EDIT:**

As OP is asking for constraints between container view, label and cell, I am updating answer to reflect the same

[image]

Clearly

```
  - - - - - - - - - - - - Cell - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|       - - - - - - - - Container View - - - - - - - -          |
|     |                      |5                          |      |   
|-10- |-5-                  Label                     -5-| -10- |   
|     |                      |5                          |      |
|       - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -       |
|                                                               |
  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

You can add top and bottom constraint between cell and conatiner if you need, but I have kept container view vertically center to cell

**How it works?**

Label has intrinsic content-size which it gets from the text set to it, View does gets its intrinsic size based on the size of its subview, because there are no subviews in your container view, it gets its size from label and clearly whatever the size label returns view adds 10 to width and 10 to height ( 5 leading, 5 trailing, 5 top and 5 bottom) finally cell gets its size from its subviews, because there is only one subview (container view) it gets width from container view and for height it gets its height from collection view (as subviews dont provide enough data to calculate its height)

And if for some reason (might be because of some other constraints you have set knowingly / unknowingly like adding width constraint on container view) label is not taking its intrinsic content size correctly, you can always set `setContentCompressionResistancePriority` and `setContentHuggingPriority` on label to high in your cell's awake from nib

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        self.label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
 }
```

Though this shouldnt be needed in usual case, if this is needed to get correct intrinsic size, there must be some other constraints which are preventing the label to take its proper implicit intrinsic content size, if I were in your position would rather check and fix it first. Nonetheless cant debug further with limited code you have provided.

**EDIT 2:**

Did not realize that OP is using custom instance of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and has not set `estimatedItemSize` property to `automaticSize`

```
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
        layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Comment: if we did not give top and bottom or height of the view then it shows error, right?

Comment: i added ur above code.. but how to give constraints to containerview and label

Comment: i need same your o/p please guide me here

Comment: did u give height of the collectionview

Comment: please add collectionview and containerview and label constraints

Comment: Gimme sometime, afk right now will update answer soon

Comment: @iosswift: You havent added my code, I can still see that you are setting `layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.size.width / 2, height: 80)` and you are still calling `layout.invalidateLayout()` it doesnt make any sense, can you update the question and add what you have right now?

Comment: Yes I have a height constraint to collection view, its a collection view with horizontal scroll, obviously it needs to know the height, as you are returning the hard coded size 80 as height you can simply set that as height of collection view rather than returning it as size of item

Comment: lemme add constraints I added between container and label and cell

Comment: i have updated my question with your code and its output

Comment: @iosswift: Have you set the constraints properly?

Comment: make sure you dont have width constraint on cell, container view

Comment: u explained me very well but.. i did not get.. i have updated my constraints in question. but same o/p

Comment: @iosswift Have you tried setting `setContentCompressionResistancePriority` and `setContentHuggingPriority` to label? also are you 100% sure you havent set sizeForItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: @iosswift: Got the issue, updated my answer, its because you havent set `estimatedItemSize` to `automaticSize`

Comment: @iosswift: Hey have you tried the last update setting `layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize` I used your code as is and this was the only statement missing its working fine now