# How do I programmatically expand the collection view cell according to the label

Tags: swift, uikit, label, collectionview

I have labels in my collection view cells. But these labels are moving out of the cells. How do I set the cell width according to the length of the label?

**This is my page :**

[image]

**I want this :**

[image]

[How to change CollectionView cell width according to label text in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66609863/how-to-change-collectionview-cell-width-according-to-label-text-in-swift)

I tried this question but unfortunately it didn't work. The difference between this question and my question is that I don't use storyboard.

**Collection View :**

```
    private let wordsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        
        // Specify the frame and layout of the UICollectionView
        let wordsCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        wordsCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        wordsCollectionView.register(WordsCustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: WordsCustomCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        wordsCollectionView.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
        return wordsCollectionView
    }()
```

**WordsCustomCollectionViewCell :**

class WordsCustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
private let wordsLabel: UILabel = {
    let wordsLabel = UILabel()
    wordsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    wordsLabel.text = "#eagle"
    wordsLabel.textColor = .systemGray6
    wordsLabel.backgroundColor = .red
    wordsLabel.sizeToFit()
    return wordsLabel
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configureUI()
}

private func configureUI() {
    contentView.addSubViews(wordsLabel)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        wordsLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
        wordsLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor)
    ])
    wordsLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
    wordsLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code size relies on sizeToFit() for label sizing. The cell size may not accurately adjust to the label's content but at below it relies on the constraints within the cell. And also add `numberOfLines` in order to set to display text in a single line.

Collection View:

```
private let wordsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1

let wordsCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
wordsCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
wordsCollectionView.register(WordsCustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: WordsCustomCollectionViewCell.identifier)
wordsCollectionView.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
return wordsCollectionView 
}()
```

WordsCustomCollectionViewCell:

```
class WordsCustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

private let wordsLabel: UILabel = {
    let wordsLabel = UILabel()
    wordsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    wordsLabel.text = "#eagle"
    wordsLabel.textColor = .systemGray6
    wordsLabel.backgroundColor = .red
    wordsLabel.numberOfLines = 1 // Display text in a single line
    wordsLabel.textAlignment = .center // Center the text horizontally
    return wordsLabel
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configureUI()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func configureUI() {
    contentView.addSubview(wordsLabel)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        wordsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        wordsLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        wordsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        wordsLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
    ])
}

// Set the label text when configuring the cell
func configure(withText text: String) {
    wordsLabel.text = text
}
```

}

Comment: That's true, but if layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 40) is a long label, it goes to line 2 and breaks the view.

Comment: I understand the problem now. Can you please check the edited answer?

Comment: It's try. Thanks!

Comment: @berkaneks - while this answer *may* solve the issue, it is much better to point out what your code is doing differently than the OP's code, and **explain** why it makes a difference.

Comment: Explaination added.

Comment: `.numberOfLines` default is `1`, so no need to set that. The key point was that the label was simply centered in the contentView... the "fix" was to add leading and trailing constraints.